# Import a .txt file that uses UTF-8 character encoding

Tags: stata

How to import a .txt file that uses UTF-8 character encoding on **stata 13**?

Comment: Unicode support was [added in Stata 14](http://www.stata.com/stata14/unicode/).

Answer (score 3):

```
import delimited <filename>, charset(utf8)
```

As mentioned, Stata 13 does not support utf8, but **import delimited** can convert it for Stata 13 as long as the characters you are importing can be represented using an extended ASCII encoding.